# Python list operation error : unhashable type 'list'

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, runtime-error

I have the below list.

```
A = [['a', 10], ['b', 50], ['d', 20],['b', 50]]
```

why can't I do :

```
B = set(A)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I'm not using a dictionary as you can see.
A is a list of lists.

```
>>>type(A) 
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: You're using a set, which is basically a dictionary without values.

Comment: This "already answered question" wouldn't have helped much.
I just posted a simplified and straight forward version of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A set requires its members to be hashable as well.  You should use a list of tuples instead of a list of lists:

```
A = [('a', 10), ('b', 50), ('d', 20), ('b', 50)]
```

A set is basically a dictionary without values for the keys.